# Oracle type DATE

Tags: java, oracle

I have field type DATE in database table

I need to select information by date range:

```
select  to_char(log_hour, ' DD/MM/YY HH24')  from  log_hourly_page page_counts where to_char(log_hour, 'DD/MM/YY') = '25/06/13'  order by log_hour desc;
```

and I am getting right results (many records for each hour)

```
 25/06/13 23
 25/06/13 23
 25/06/13 23
 25/06/13 22

...........

 25/06/13 04
 25/06/13 04
 25/06/13 00
 25/06/13 00
```

But when  I run

```
select  to_char(log_hour, ' DD/MM/YY HH24')  from  log_hourly_page page_counts where log_hour = '25-Jun-2013'  order by log_hour desc;
```

I always get 0 as my hour,

```
 25/06/13 00
 25/06/13 00
 25/06/13 00
 25/06/13 00
.............
 25/06/13 00
 25/06/13 00
 25/06/13 00
```

Why second query works this way? I testing this query since I pass Java.util.Date object as date and it returns wrong data, always 00 hour.

Comment: Retrieve the `DATE` field as Date in the SELECT statement, then in your Java code use `ResultSet#getTimestamp(1)` and associate this to a `java.util.Date` field.

Comment: Luiggi Mendoza - I did not really understand your solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a time component to a date specified in this way in Oracle:

```
'25-Jun-2013'
```

and the time component is 0 (midnight), and the hour is 0, so you will only get matches from that specific point in time, and not from the whole day.

To get the entire day's range, use what you already have:

```
where to_char(log_hour, 'DD/MM/YY') = '25/06/13'
```

or use a range:

```
where log_hour >= '25/06/13' and log_hour < '26/06/13'
```

**EDIT**

Now I get to see your actual Java code:

```
query.setDate("date", date);
```

That passes a SQL DATE which has no time component.

You want to use [`setTimestamp`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setTimestamp%28int,%20java.sql.Timestamp%29), which passes a SQL TIMESTAMP to the database, which has a time component as well as the date component.

```
query.setTimestamp("date", timestamp);
```

Comment: anyway to adjust it on Java end, right now I just pass java.util.date as parameter - query.setDate("date", date); date has type Date, and I always get 00. Seems like the same problem

Comment: if use RANGE I have always increment incoming data from datePicker

Comment: Thanks for supplying the actual Java code here; all I saw previously was your SQL.

Comment: yes, sorry I did not mention it before. I still have the same problem, only 00 in results after query.setTimestamp("fromDate", proxyParams.getFromDate()); the same as query.setDate("fromDate", proxyParams.getFromDate());. proxyParams.getFromDate() - Date type, assigned value comes as post request, 24/06/2013

Comment: What is the time value part of `proxyParams.getFromDate()`?  It will still attempt to match the exact date and time.

Comment: no time value, just string coming from datePicker as 06/25/2013
and just set it to Date date. Thats it

Answer (score 1):

If you have an index on `log_hour`, Oracle will optimize the query *unless* you apply a function like `TO_CHAR` or `TRUNC` against it.

Also, I'd recommend using the ANSI date syntax because it always works. Your `where log_hour = '25-Jun-2013'` depends on Oracle's date format setting, which is `DD-MON-RR` in most installations but it can be changed. If you try `'25-Jun-2013'` and Oracle is using a different format, the query will fail.

```
select to_char(log_hour, ' DD/MM/YY HH24')
from log_hourly_page page_counts
where log_hour >= DATE '2013-06-25' AND log_hour < DATE '2013-06-26'
order by log_hour desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is

```
private DateTimeFormatter processHourFormat = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendMonthOfYear(2)
                                                                                    .appendLiteral('/')
                                                                                    .appendDayOfMonth(2)
                                                                                    .appendLiteral('/')
                                                                                    .appendYear(4, 4)                        
                                                                                    .toFormatter();

private SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");




DateTime dateTimeFrom = DateTime.parse(dateFormat.format(proxyParams.getFromDate()), processHourFormat).withHourOfDay(00);
DateTime dateTimeTo   = DateTime.parse(dateFormat.format(proxyParams.getToDate()), processHourFormat).withHourOfDay(23);



 query.setTimestamp("fromDate", dateTimeFrom.toDate());
   query.setTimestamp("toDate", dateTimeTo.toDate());
```

Thanks everybody for help.